# Regex match MAC Addresses (different delimiters, formatting, etc.)

Tags: python, regex, network-programming, mac-address, regex-lookarounds

I was trying to find a Python compatible Regex expression that would be best for matching MAC addresses, but exclude things that might be mistaken for them (*e.g.*, SSH keys). Also, I'd like to match the different delimiters (*e.g.*, **-**, **:**, or **.**), different formatting (*e.g.*, *nix, Windows, Cisco), and a string (*e.g.*, no delimiters).

Also, I'm trying to find the *shortest* answer (*i.e.*, regex) possible that would achieve my requirements.

---

Here's some example data to help narrow down the possibilities:

*Must match the MAC addresses (i.e., excluding extra special characters) found in:*

```
(13:14:5f:cD:42:5f)
#13-14-5f-cD-42-5f
13.14.5f.cD.42.5f/
1314:5fcD:425f#
"1314.5fcD.425f"
1314-5fcD-425f
13145fcD425f
#13145fcD425f:
```

*Must not match any of the following:*

```
56:32:13:14:5f:cD:42:5f:65
56-32-13-14-5f-cD-42-5f-65
56.32.13.14.5f.cD.42.5f.65
13:14:5f:cD:42:5f:
:13:14:5f:cD:42:5f
111113:14:5f:cD:42:5ffff
ff13:14:5f:cD:42:5f
1314-5fcD.425f
1314-5f.cD:425f
13:14.5f:cD:42-5f
45fcD4
fcD4
13145fcD425f13145fcD425f
aa13145fcD425f13145fcD425fff
```

Comment: I've modified the question to include example/validation data and to ask for the shortest answer. Was my post reevaluated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I eventually came up with. I'll try to outline the details below in the section titled notes. I intentionally left in three redundant/unnecessary non-capturing groups, but this helps delimit the code for each of the three paths.

I'd greatly appreciate your feedback. Thanks.

---

```
\b(?:(?<![-:\.])(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}(?=([-:\.]))(?:\1[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}){5})|(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}(?=([-:\.]))(?:\2[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}){2}))(?![-:\.])|(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}))\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/IoEhEXTGiJIc2neb)

**Notes:**

- I wrote the regex to **strict**-*ly* match the delimiters, meaning the delimiters within the MAC address must be the same throughout the entire match via backreferences (*e.g.*, hh:hh:hh:hh:hh:hh, NOT hh-hh:hh.hh:hh-hh & NOT hh:hh:hh:hh:hh-hh)
- The delimiters are grouped in square brackets `[]` and represents that any item inside may match
- The three primary delimiters used throughout are `[-:\.]` dash/hyphen, colon, and period/dot respectively.
- I escaped the `\.` (dot) as it has an ambiguous meaning (*e.g.*, `.` can mean *any* character, which is not what I want).
- All but two of my groups are non-capturing groups, so they begin with `(?:` and end with the matching `)`.
- `|` (pipe) represents OR, causing the branches
- `\b` (word boundary) prevents matches found in the middle of strings (*e.g.*, line 7-8, 19-20)
- **Path:1**

  - `(?<![-:\.])` &  `(?![-:\.])` (negative lookbehind and negative lookahead) prevents matches as found in SSH keys (though only colon may be required here, can't say I've seen the other two delimiters used for keys)
  - **Path:1.1** *nix/Windows matching format: pairs of hex chars delimited (*e.g.*, hh:hh:hh:hh:hh:hh)

    - `[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}` hex char repeated two times
    - `(?=([-:\.]))` lookahead & capture (the inner parens) the delimiter (capturing group `\1`)
    - `\1` matching the first delimiter stored in capturing group `\1`, `(?:\1[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}){5}` repeat the delimiter & hex pair pattern five more times
  - **Path:1.2** Cisco matching format: quad hex chars delimited (*e.g.*, hhhh.hhhh.hhhh)

    - `[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}` hex char repeated four times
    - `(?=([-:\.]))` lookahead & capture (the inner parens) the delimiter (capturing group `\2`)
    - `\2` matching the second delimiter stored in capturing group `\2`, `(?:\2[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}){2}` repeat the delimiter & four hex chars pattern two more times
- **Path:2** string matching format: all 12 hex chars, non-delimited (*e.g.*, hhhhhhhhhhhh)

  - `[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}` hex char repeated twelve times
  - Does not require the absence of delimiters before or after string as none are used within, and ability to match example lines 9 & 16 (but still follow the word boundaries)

To meet the shortest possible answer, as requested by the OP, from the answer above I've removed the non-capturing groups (*i.e.*, made them all capturing groups) and the extra groupings for clarity, I get **140** chars:

```
\b((?<![-:\.])([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}(?=([-:\.]))(\3[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}){5}|[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}(?=([-:\.]))(\5[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}){2})(?![-:\.])|[0-9A-Fa-f]{12})\b
```

---

Here's a sample I used for validation:

```
56:32:13:14:5f:cD:42:5f:65
(13:14:5f:cD:42:5f)
#13-14-5f-cD-42-5f
56-32-13-14-5f-cD-42-5f-65
13.14.5f.cD.42.5f/
56.32.13.14.5f.cD.42.5f.65
111113:14:5f:cD:42:5ffff
ff13:14:5f:cD:42:5f
1314:5fcD:425f#
1314.5fcD.425f)
1314-5fcD-425f
1314-5fcD.425f
1314-5f.cD:425f
13:14.5f:cD:42-5f
13145fcD425f
#13145fcD425f:
45fcD4
fcD4
13145fcD425f13145fcD425f
aa13145fcD425f13145fcD425fff
```